# Get provider string .net framework for oledb

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I know the version number of an Access engine? And how can get full string `provider` for `oledb` ?

For example:

```
provider="microsoft.ace.jet.12.0"
```

in vb.net or C#.

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain why you want to know this info? Probably we can help you better if you explain the reason that triggered this question

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to know it? Since you get the string by deciding what you want to use. Otherwise you need to check the registry.

I checked for specific one like this:

```
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0")
```

The full string is just whatever you use and location:

```
"Provider=<what you use>;Data Source=<location>"
```